# Tab bar with fragments - add fragments

Tags: android, android-fragments

I've implemented a tab bar using ViewPager and fragments with a listview. When tap one of the list items, I have a CallBack to the MainActivity which will handle the action. Now I have to add another fragment on top of the existing one in the right tab. I try it with

```
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putInt("Tab", tab);
        args.putIntegerArrayList("Sel", sel);
        sel.add(position);
        Tab1Fragment newFragment = new Tab1Fragment();
        newFragment.setArguments(args);
        FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        transaction.add(R.id.content, newFragment);
        transaction.addToBackStack(null);
        transaction.commit();
```

This code is working, but not necessarily on the tab I want.
I have four tabs, each with a fragment. Therefore, I must address the correct fragment in which happened the action. Which of my four fragments will be overlayed with this code? How can I here address a specific fragment?

Comment: Is `R.id.content` your ViewPager?

Comment: In the tab where you want another fragment , use frameLayout in that fragment and then inflate your fragment in that frame.

Answer (score 0):

What i understand from your question is you want to add a fragment on the current fragment whose list item is clicked... If this is the case provide id (R.id.content i.e. in your case) of your current fragment base layout(FrameLayout in general case). In general if you want to add a fragment then container base layout should be FrameLayout. So that new fragment view can be overlaid on current view of your fragment.

Let me know if this is not the case...

Comment: The problem was another one. I did initialize the parameter "Sel" with the same empty instance of "sel" for all four fragments. When I had to modify this parameter in one fragment, it had the same value in other fragments too. Therefore the other fragments behaved exactly like the actual fragment. That's why I had the impression that the wrong segments have been addressed. (I use the same Tab1Fragment for all four tabs. What they show is depending on the parameters. Same parameters = same display.)

Comment: @thpitsch as for "Sel", you would be passing an arraylist.. first thing when we pass a serializable object, it becomes a new object whose reference is not the same as what you have. So later when you do any change using the list reference you have wont effect the current fragment list elements. If you want to update fragment view later then have a reference of fragment and use method directly to update.

Comment: You are right, the arraylist itself becomes a new object. But at "args.putIntegerArrayList("Sel", sel)" I put something on it, that was declared before as "ArrayList<Integer> sel = new ArrayList<Integer>()". This "sel" ist the same object, when I put it on different bundles. And if I change it, the change is effective on all fragments. Now I do "args.putIntegerArrayList("Sel", new ArrayList<Integer>())" and the problem is gone.